# Unable to find ionic version after updating ionic 1 to ionic 2 (error on shell.js)

Tags: node.js, angular, installation, ionic2, npm-install

I am working on windows10 for my ionic1.

I tried to install ionic2 in my pc and i am not able to create my ionic project and i am not able see the version of ionic

I don't see anything related to ionic.

When i try to get the version of ionic using this command `ionic -v` i am not able to

get my version i am getting the error which i have placed in the below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiK1h.png)

> things i did so far is done is command for installing ionic 2 `npm install -g
>
> ionic@beta`

Before entering the above command i was able to work with ionic1 good.

Comment: please make sure any other terminals or IDEs or such don't have this file open..

Comment: @Subburaj i am very new to ionic 2 i would like to know how can i find weather that is open or not please help me i very poor in indicating the path

Answer (score 0):

To see your ionic version, you have to run a terminal. Then go inside your ionic project folder and run the command : `ionic --version`.

It should show you the current version you are using in this particular project.

To install ionic be sure you are login as `root`, if you still have issue, try to delete everything related to `ionic` and try again.